# Does DatePicker in flutter uses native android widget or its a custom widget in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

When working on a Flutter project that involved handling dates, I noticed that the DatePicker widget looked very similar to the native Android date picker.

I'm curious to know whether DatePicker is a custom implementation in Flutter or if it uses a method to invoke the native Android date picker.

#### In Flutter:

[image: Date Picker in Flutter]

#### In Native Android:

[image: Native Date Picker in android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom implementation. I couldn't find any use of

- PlatformViewLink (Hybrid composition)
- AndroidView (Virtual display)

in the **date_picker.dart** and **calendar_date_picker.dart**

You can see in the files how it is implemented.